# Substitute a constant in a differential equation of second order

Tags: sympy, differential-equations

I managed to calculate constants but I don't know how to swap the constant in C1. Can anyone help please? :)

```
import sympy as sym
x, g, K, m, t = sym.symbols('x, g, K, m, t', positive=True, real=True)
dxx = sym.Eq(x(t).diff(t, 2), g - K/m*x(t).diff(t))
rešitev = sym.dsolve(dxx) 
y_res = rešitev.args[1] 
C2_enačba = sym.Eq(sym.diff(y_res.subs(x, 0), t), 0)
C2 = sym.solve(C2_enačba, 'C2')
display(C2)
C1_subs = y_res.subs(x, 0)
C1_enačba = sym.Eq(C1_subs, 0)
C1 = sym.solve(C1_enačba, 'C1') 
display(C1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitution can be done with `subs`:

```
rešitev.subs({sym.Symbol('C1'): C1[0], sym.Symbol('C2'): C2[0]})
```

However, the process by which you found the constants was incorrect; you can see that the "constants" contain the variable t. This is because of a mixup of x and t in the formulas. Here is the corrected version:

```
import sympy as sym
x, g, K, m, t = sym.symbols('x, g, K, m, t', positive=True, real=True)
dxx = sym.Eq(x(t).diff(t, 2), g - K/m*x(t).diff(t))
rešitev = sym.dsolve(dxx) 
y_res = rešitev.args[1] 
C2_enačba = sym.Eq(sym.diff(y_res, t).subs(t, 0), 0)   # derivative at 0 is 0
C2 = sym.solve(C2_enačba, 'C2')
C1_subs = y_res.subs(t, 0)                           
C1_enačba = sym.Eq(C1_subs, 0)                         # the value at 0 is 0
C1 = sym.solve(C1_enačba, 'C1') 
answer = rešitev.subs({sym.Symbol('C1'): C1[0], sym.Symbol('C2'): C2[0]})
```

The answer is

```
Eq(x(t), g*m*t/K - g*m**2/K**2 + g*m**2*exp(-K*t/m)/K**2)
```

---

But your code could be much simpler if you use the [current master branch of  SymPy](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/) from GitHub, in which the initial and boundary conditions in `dsolve` are implemented.

```
import sympy as sym
x, g, K, m, t = sym.symbols('x, g, K, m, t', positive=True, real=True)
dxx = sym.Eq(x(t).diff(t, 2), g - K/m*x(t).diff(t))
ics = {x(0): 0, x(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): 0}
answer = sym.dsolve(dxx, ics=ics)
```

The answer is same as above,

```
Eq(x(t), g*m*t/K - g*m**2/K**2 + g*m**2*exp(-K*t/m)/K**2)
```

Comment: Everything works thanks very much! :) The only problem I have left is to plot the found exspression. I use sym.lambdify(t, answer.args[1], 'numpy') and try to plot it with sympy and it returns an error that says 'zero' object has no attribute exp if you have any idea what could be wrong.

Comment: lambdify is needed when you use some expression outside of SymPy. You don't need it within SymPy. Just substitute numeric values for g, m, K and plot: `sym.plot(answer.rhs.subs({g: 9.8, m: 2, K: 0.1}), (t, 0, 2))`.